# passing value to method in jquery coundown plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery countdown plugin with the following code.

```
$('#countbox').countdown({

layout:'<b>{d<}{dnn}:{d>}'+ 
    '{hnn}: {mnn} : {snn} </b>',
timeSeparator: ':', 
onExpiry: sold,
onTick: highlight,
serverSync: serverTime

});
function serverTime(pid) { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_countdown', 
        async: false,
        data: ({pid:pid}),
        dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        },
         error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }}); 
    alert(time);
    return time; 
}
```

Question 1: using this I'm calling the function `serverTime` and I want to pass the value `pid` to the method. How do I achieve this ?

---

Question 2 is related to the javascript `Date` function

```
$d4 ="2011,01-1,11,23,31,32";
alert(new Date(<?php echo $d4; ?>));
```

when I run the above code I get following result

> Tue Jan 11 2011 23:31:32 GMT+0530
>   (India Standard Time)

But, the ajax call (as above) also returns the same result, yet in this case when I alert, I receive the following response

> Invalid Date
>
> alert(time);

Why is this different in the second case and how can I alter my code to receive my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer myself for this
Question 1: using this i 'm calling function serverTime . here i want to pass the value pid to the method.how to do this ?

The code snippet not yet tested but i hope it will work.

```
 $('#countbox').countdown({

    layout:'<b>{d<}{dnn}:{d>}'+ 
        '{hnn}: {mnn} : {snn} </b>',
    timeSeparator: ':', 
    onExpiry: sold,
    onTick: highlight,
    serverSync: function() { serverTime(pid); }

    });

function serverTime(pid) { 
    alert(pid);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "alert" fires before the ajax answer returns... include it into the success function... or call a function from success..

```
function serverTime(pid) { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_countdown', 
        async: false,
        data: ({pid:pid}),
        dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
            alert(time);
            return time; 
        },
         error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }}); 
}
```

Comment: When you alert(text) it REALLY returns the same string? And can you check the encoding and mimetype of the ajax post answer (e.g. with firebug in FF or developer tools in chrome)?